# Find optimal combination within dataframe which gives maximum overall average using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, maximize

Suppose there is a data frame and statistics as following table:

| Time | A | B | C | D | E | Combination A~E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 5 | 8 | -8 | 7.00 |
| 2 | 20 | -3 | 6 | -5 | 10 | 5.60 |
| 3 | -5 | 40 | 5 | 4 | 20 | 12.80 |
| 4 | 6 | -8 | 2 | 18 | 5 | 4.60 |
| 5 | 8 | -1 | -4 | -5 | 4 | 0.40 |
| Average | 7.80 | 9.60 | 2.80 | 4.00 | 6.20 | 6.08 |
| Standard Deviation | 8.01 | 17.96 | 3.66 | 8.65 | 9.09 | 4.02 |
| Ratio (Average/S.D) | 0.97 | 0.53 | 0.77 | 0.46 | 0.68 | 1.51 |

According to the above table, combination of all A~E give the overall average of 6.08, standard deviation of 4.02 and the ratio of 1.51.

By removing some of the columns A ~ E, maybe I can maximize the average, minimize the standard deviation, or doing the both (increasing the ratio).

(*Meaning that I will remove the entire values in the column, not individual value in each row)

Is there any way I can find out the "best combination" of the columns from A to E which give the:

A) Maximum average

B) Minimum standard deviation

C) Maximum ratio of A/B?

Desired answer might be something like:
A, B, C
A, B, E
A, B, C, D
or even A, B, C, D, E

Comment: So, you need that for every row or looking the best combination in the whole data frame.

Comment: And what have you tried? Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I am looking the best combination in the whole data frame.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato I have been through trial and error in excel, and I don't think it is clever away to approach, but I have no idea how to start with. Would you give small tips?

Comment: You need the items A), B) and C) for each row or just get the best combination for the whole df. Please answer what we ask in order to help you.

Comment: What does "best combination" mean (please show examples of calculations)? Are you sure you can meet all criteria at once? If not, how to select among top candidates? What would be the answer for this example?

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos The best combination for the whole df

Comment: Repeating again "*the best combination*" doesn't make it more explicit. ;)

Comment: @mozway As stated above, there are three types of best combination here: maximum average, minimum standard deviation, and the maximum ratio. For simplicity, let's focus on maximum average. For five individual elements (A~E), possible combination is 2 X 2 X 2 X 2 X 2 = 32. I would like to look for which of 32 combination makes the maximum average.

Answer (score 2):

For finding the best matching subset of each row you can create all possible subsets then find the max/min as you wish. For example the following code compute the best cols for the first condition:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def com(row):
    s = []
    for i in range(2, len(row)+1):
       s.extend([x for x in itertools.combinations(row.values, i)])
    vals = s[np.argmax([np.mean(x) for x in s])]
    return row[row.isin(vals)].index.values

df.apply(com, axis = 1)
```

for the first two rows the result is as follows:

```
1    [A, B]
2    [A, E]
dtype: object
```

Based on the comment this may helps:

```
string = '''Time    A   B   C   D   E
Average 7.80    9.60    2.80    4.00    6.20
Standard Deviation  8.01    17.96   3.66    8.65    9.09
Ratio (Average/S.D) 0.97    0.53    0.77    0.46    0.68'''
data = np.array([x.split('  ') for x in string.split('\n')])
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:,1:], columns = data[0,1:], index = data[1:,0])
df = df.astype(float)

df.apply(com, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
Average                [A, B]
Standard Deviation     [B, E]
Ratio (Average/S.D)    [A, C]
dtype: object
```

You can choose the best based on your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is a good way to start. Instead of finding the best combination for each row, is there any way to find the best combination for the entire dataframe?

Comment: Yes, actually i was thinking about it. Are you ok to first get the average of each column and then apply the above code?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer again.

Comment: I tried the code but looks to me that my data frame is too heavy to run itertools package! I ran the code with the data frame size of 3 rows X 170 columns and it didn't work because of the memory error. I changed it into 3 rows X 42 columns, still doesn't work. But thank you for help!

Comment: Have you any restriction on the number of columns to use? I mean for example maybe you do not want combinations with more than 10 or something similar? Also please note that I think the idea behind methodology has some kind of problem. Because for the mean every time it will calculate the mean of the first two biggest numbers. By the way, if you can provide your data or something similar to it, maybe I can help.

Comment: Actually I want the combination number to be something between 10 to 20 using 170 elements. But then it looks like the outcome will be the top 10 ~ 20 biggest numbers. So I need to develop codes which can calculate averages of all possible combinations ( = 2^n numbers of combinations), which can then be used to calculate the total average and standard deviation, which can then be used for comparison.

Comment: So, change for i in range(2, len(row)+1) to for i in range(10, 20). Maybe it can save your memory.